# Why does searching for a string that ends in Null result in extra quotes?

Tags: bug, status-planned, search

If I type this in the (main) search box:

> [visual-studio] "Unexpected Null"

It changes my search query to:

> "[visual-studio] "Unexpected Null""

I can change my query to anything that ends in "Null":

> [visual-studio] "Unexpected Quotes around Null"
>
> [visual-studio] "Something is Null"

And if it returns any results at all, it adds quotes around the entire search query.

This seems to only happen when the tag has hyphens in it ([javascript] tag doesn't trigger it, [windows-service] does).

Firefox Windows 10

Comment: Are you referring to the text that appears at the top? `results found containing unexpected null "[visual-studio] " ""`

Comment: @KevinB, no the search box itself changes.

Comment: Not happening here.

Comment: Attention, Bizarre Bug Department... we have a situation!

Comment: Ah, i see, it is happening, what it's doing is redirecting you because it found no results. It's trying something else that *does* have results. `Could not find any results for [visual-studio] "Unexpected Null"; showing 17 results for "[visual-studio] "Unexpected Null"",
`

Comment: @KevinB why would restricting the search to an exact search produce **more** results?

Comment: because with the updated search term it's looking for the words 'visual' and 'studio' which does have results, rather than looking for results within that tag.

Comment: i mean, looking at the results, it's obviously not doing an exact search. Whether or not that's a bug, i dunno.

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me... hence [meta-tag:bug]

Comment: And actually searching for `"[visual-studio] "Unexpected Null""` returns 122 results. Not 17. Looks like you need to search `[visual-studio] "[visual-studio] "Unexpected Null""` to get the 17.

Comment: My point was more so that the quotes showing up can be explained, though the results by doing so are weird. your question seemed to focus on the quotes.

Comment: I think the new query it tried should *not* include the tag within it, or, at least not include the tag as part of the quoted text. that just seems really odd. I can think of situations where that makes sense, for example if you wanted to search for questions that contained "[foobar]". first it would do a tag search, and then upon finding nothing it would do a text search. but... it doesn't even do that. it just tells you there's no results without giving any indication that it tried any other combinations, unlike what you observed with your query.

Comment: For me the tag doesn't matter.  All that matters is that the exact string isn't found.  For example, the search `[visual-studio] "is null"` doesn't mess up.  But `[javascript] "exact string not found null"` does.  This seems to confirm @KevinB's idea that it's a redirect or other logic at play trying to "fix" your search to produce any results.

Comment: i recall a meta post recently that mentioned this being something they're working on, but i can't find it.

Comment: yes, this is by design. A quoted search is attempted if there are no results for the unquoted search.

Comment: @m0sa, why does the quoted search include results where the keywords do not appear as a phrase (just individually)?

Comment: ugh yeah, the quoting logic seems to be buggy ... it attempts a quoted search despite the query already containing quotes. In your case, it inverts the quotes you added... it effectively searches for `"visual studio" unexpected null`... we should probably not attempt a quoted search if the query string already contains quotes.

Comment: At that rate, why even attempt a quoted search at all? When done correctly, results without quotes are guaranteed to be equal to or higher than results where only the exact phrase is returned.  Also, I've noticed this behavior on Chem.SE too, so maybe this should be on Meta.SE instead of Meta.SO.

Comment: there is some additional syntax processing we do on unquoted queries (tag detection, advanced operators, etc.). The quoted search is attempted on the entire query string, if the processed query didn't return any results. The quoted search add quotes around the original unprocessed query string, so the results can differ in some cases.

Comment: [Fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/275815/364344) in the overall build 2018.1.8.28296.